# Python subprocess, mysqldump and pipes

Tags: python, subprocess, mysql

I've got a problem trying to build a easy backup/upgrade database script.

The error is in the mysqldump call using subprocess:

```
cmdL = ["mysqldump", "--user=" + db_user, "--password=" + db_pass, domaindb + "|", "gzip", ">", databases_path + "/" + domaindb + ".sql.gz"]
print "%s: backup database %s \n\t[%s]" % (domain, domaindb, ' '.join(cmdL))
total_log.write("%s: backup database %s \n\t[%s] \n" % (domain, domaindb, ' '.join(cmdL)))
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Before that cose, i redirect `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to files, in order to have a log system.

In those log, i find the error:

[mysqldump --user=xxxxxx --password=yyyyyyyy database_name | gzip > /home/drush-backup/2010-08-30.15.37/db/database_name.sql]
[Error]: mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "|"

Seem that the `|` character is seen as an mysqldump arguments, instead as a pipe.

Looking into the python subprocess documentation, this is normal, but how can i obtain what i need (call the command `mysqldump --user=xxxxxx --password=yyyyyyyy database_name | gzip > /home/drush-backup/2010-08-30.15.37/db/database_name.sql`)?

**EDIT** I just see this example on python docs:

```
output=`dmesg | grep hda`
==>
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

and i've edit my script:

```
command = ["mysqldump", "--user=" + db_user, "--password=" + db_pass, domaindb, "|", "gzip", ">", databases_path + "/" + domaindb + ".sql.gz"]
cmdL1 = ["mysqldump", "--user=" + db_user, "--password=" + db_pass, domaindb]
cmdL2 = ["gzip", ">", databases_path + "/" + domaindb + ".sql.gz"]

print "%s: backup database %s \n\t[%s]" % (domain, domaindb, ' '.join(command))
total_log.write("%s: backup database %s \n\t[%s] \n" % (domain, domaindb, ' '.join(command)))

p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmdL1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(cmdL2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
cmdError, cmdData = p2.communicate()
```

now the command variable is just used for convenience in logs.

This go a step next but it stops in the `>` stream, with this error:

```
[Error]: gzip: >: No such file or directory
gzip: /path/to/backups/dir/natabase_name.sql.gz: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, if i try the command in a terminal it works.

Comment: The commas add a space, but the plus sign does not.  domaindb and the pipe are joined with a plus.  Maybe that is the problem?  Not sure why you are joining strings with the commas rather than just using spaces and keeping them within the same quotation marks.

Comment: Becose im newbie in python ;) anyway, I think I have to use the +, becose there must be no space between `--user=` and the db_user.. the correct form should be `--user=foo`, or am i mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of how the pipe will get interpreted.  If that's a problem, you can programatically create a pipelilne.

from:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

*edit*

As for file redirection, you can direct stdout to a file..

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the
>   executed programs’ standard input,
>   standard output and standard error
>   file handles, respectively. Valid
>   values are PIPE, an existing file
>   descriptor (a positive integer), an
>   existing file object, and None.

Example:

```
out_file = open(out_filename, "wb")
gzip_proc = subprocess.Popen("gzip", stdout=out_file)
gzip_proc.communicate()
```

or if you take Alex's advice and use Python's standard library [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) module, you can do something like this:

```
import gzip
import subprocess

...
#out_filename = path to gzip file

cmdL1 = ["mysqldump", "--user=" + db_user, "--password=" + db_pass, domaindb]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmdL1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
dump_output = p1.communicate()[0]

f = gzip.open(out_filename, "wb")
f.write(dump_output)
f.close()
```

Comment: i just did and edited my question; now it broke with the `>` step

Answer (score 5):

With path, user, pswd and dbname given, the following works like a charm:

```
import gzip
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = "mysqldump --user={user} --password={pswd} {dbname}".format(**locals())        
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
with gzip.open(path, "wb") as f:
    f.writelines(p.stdout)
```

using `f` as stdout argument in `subprocess.Popen()` also works but does not compress the data.
Before Python 2.7, the `with` statement does not work, so use `f=gzip.open(..)` and `f.close()`. Errors can be read with `p.stderr.read()`, so if this is not an empty string, you better raise an exception

---

To **restore the backup** you can do the following:

```
cmd = "mysql --user={user} --password={pswd} {dbname}".format(**locals())
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
with gzip.open(path, "rb") as f:
    p.stdin.write(f.read())
    p.communicate()[0]
    p.stdin.close()
    p_err = p.stderr.read()
if p_err:
    raise Exception('Error restoring database:\n{0}'.format(p_err))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `subprocess.Popen(' '.join(cmdL), shell=True)`.

Pipelines (and redirections) are recognized as such and scheduled by the **shell**, and, by default (on Unix), `subprocess` avoids using a shell (it's slower and gives you less control) -- you need to explicitly force a shell to be in control, if a pipeline or redirection is what you absolutely must have.

Normally one tries to avoid pipelines (and therefore avoid `shell=True` and the attendand issues) by doing as much of that as possible in Python (e.g., in your case, with the `gzip` module of Python's standard library).  Of course for this one must carefully separate stdout (which is to be further processed) from stderr, as two separate pipes.