# How to copy a database with mysqldump and mysql in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, mysql, pymysql

I am writing a simple Python script to copy a MySQL database. I am attempting to copy the database based on the following SO questions and their answers: "[Copy/duplicate database without using mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794/mysql-copy-duplicate-database)", "[python subprocess and mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889465/python-subprocess-and-mysqldump)" and "[Python subprocess, mysqldump and pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600948/python-subprocess-mysqldump-and-pipes)". However, my script does not work for some reason I cannot see as the tables and the data do not appear in my new database.

I can see from my output that the mysqldump works correctly (I see a "Dump completed on..." in my output), so I think that **something is wrong with my pipeline**.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymysql
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mydb')
cur = conn.cursor()

print("Attempting to create new database...")
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydb2")
    print("Creating new database")
except Exception:
    print("Database already exists")
print()

# close connection just to be sure
cur.close()
conn.close()

print("Trying to copy old database to new database...")

args1 = ["mysqldump", "-h", "localhost", "-P", "3306", "-u", "root", "-p", "mydb"]
args2 = ["mysql", "-h", "localhost", "-P", "3306", "-u", "root", "-p", "mydb2"]

p1 = Popen(args1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p2 = Popen(args1, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p2.communicate()

print("output:")
print(output)
print()
```

As you can see I took the copy database pipeline from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111224/2541501). And at first I had the error `mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "|"` just as in [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600948/python-subprocess-mysqldump-and-pipes). So now I use two `subprocess.Popen` calls as suggested, which solved that error message.

The output variable shows that a mysqldump is performed, but I see nothing being mentioned about the mysql command.

I have tried to use `p2.wait()` and `p1.wait()` instead of `p2.communicate()` [as suggested in one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890393/2541501), but that just makes my Python script become unresponsive.

I have also tried the following:

```
output1 = p1.communicate()
output2 = p2.communicate()
```

But then both output1 and output2 show the same mysqldump output. So that was just a silly thing to do I guess..

I have also tried to use `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen`, but that also makes my script become unresponsive.

Also including `shell=True` in either `Popen` or `call` also results in the script being just unresponsive.

However, it does work to type in the command in the *command prompt* (I use Windows 8.1) as follows:

`mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p mydb | mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p mydb2`

It copies my small test database in less than three seconds.

I wish I could also get it to work in Python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know the degree of *pure Python* you want to use for the copy, but you can just delegate the entire pipe operation to the shell.

```
subprocess.Popen('mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 -u -root mydb | mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root mydb2', shell=True)
```

This should work the same way it works when you run it on the shell.

Comment: Lovely. How odd that you can't simply copy a database using SQL: obviously a deliberate choice, but why?

Answer (score 5):

One problem that I saw is on this line:

```
p2 = Popen(args1, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

It should read:

```
p2 = Popen(args2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

(args1 were being passed to the second proc, so that the program did two dumps and zero restores)

Answer (score 5):

I keep coming back to this post as I try to carry out the same task, and it occurs to me that the reason for the unresponsiveness here is the "-p" switch in your mysql and mysqldump commands. "-p" by itself means "prompt for password," so the subprocesses are unresponsive because they're waiting for a password input.

Just in case anybody else comes across this ancient thread and tries to make it work for themselves, this was a trip-up for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could run `mysqldump .. | mysql` pipeline without the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

mysql = Popen("mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p mydb2".split(),
              stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
mysqldump = Popen("mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p mydb".split(),
                  stdout=mysql.stdin)
mysql_stdout = mysql.communicate()[0]
mysqldump.wait()
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

If you don't need to pass command-line parameters that require complex (possibly non-portable) escaping, capture the exit statuses, stdout then it is simpler to use the shell here.

Comment: I didn't know we needed .wait() :)

Comment: @matiu: `mysqldump.wait()` is called to avoid creating a zombie. The `mysqldump` process itself has finished already by the time we call `.wait()`.

Comment: I'm curious: is there any advantage to use this syntax instead of an inline pipe like in the accepted answer? (except for readability, I guess)

Comment: @olinox14: the last paragraph in the answer addresses it.