# Simple database table dumping in a specific path

Tags: python, mysql

How can I dump MySQL database table only which will store my on drive 'c:', rather than whole database

here is my running python connect script:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='test',
                         password ='test',host='192.168.25.63',
                       database='test',port='3306')
```

I also refer to this question using subprocess:
[How to copy a database with mysqldump and mysql in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256248/how-to-copy-a-database-with-mysqldump-and-mysql-in-python)

I just want to have a python script just like having MySQLdump using windows command.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use following command with `popen`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.popen("mysqldump db_name table_name > your_path/table_name.sql", shell=True)
```

Comment: but how can I test if the dump is success, or where it was stored.

Comment: @Rockn'Roll You need to add the `path` at the leading of your dump name.Checkout the edit.

Comment: yup I already had that, but im still access denied, do I need to have grant privileges so that I can dump it or there is something error in my code?

Comment: CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Access is denied

Comment: Note: that im just trying to dump it to my terminal from server, not a localhost