# mysqldump from within python script but command not found

Tags: python, mysql, django, eclipse

I need to execute mysqldump from within a django function. I can do so easily enough from the terminal command line, but when I try to run it from within the python script, I get an error:

```
sh: mysqldump: command not found
```

when running the following.

```
filestamp = date.today()
dumpcmd = "mysqldump -u root appdb > appdb%s.out" % (filestamp)
os.system(dumpcmd)
```

I think the problem has something to do with the Path in either the django application or Eclipse, but I can't figure out why mysqldump can't be found from within the django app but it can be from the command line / virtualenv

Comment: You are better off using the management command `dumpdata`

Comment: but why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to automate the syncing of a database on my local machine with the same database hosted online. The first step I usually pursue is mysqldump, so I'm trying to replicate that programatically.

Comment: almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure `mysqldump` is in your path

```
$ whereis mysqldump; echo $PATH
mysqldump: /usr/bin/mysqldump /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

and/or

[using mysqldump and mysql inside python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256248/how-to-copy-a-database-with-mysqldump-and-mysql-in-python)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 -u -root appdb > appdb.sql', shell=True)
```

Or use the full path in the Python statement. e.g. `/usr/bin/mysqldump`